# "Parse" line of code doesn't allow code to execute

Tags: c, parsing

Cheers, I've isolated the error but I'm not sure how to fix it. Apparently, this line of code,(C language):

parse(getenv("QUERY_STRING"));

It does successfully compile, however when I run the executable the following pops up: puu.sh/nQi41/40e81c4494.png

When I simply comment out that specific line, the code compiles and runes perfectly.

Any possible solutions to this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more surrounding code please, to give some context.

Comment: try assigning getenv("QUERY_STRING") to some previously declared char* and tell us what it contains (by either printing it or with your debugger). Also, what does the parse function do?

Comment: `getenv` is most likely returning `NULL`, and you're not checking. You should always check the return values of functions!

Comment: @user497745 Here's the last lines of the code, for some context: http://puu.sh/nQiGA/c01ee7b7ce.png

Comment: Please do not post code as pictures. Pictures are not searchable, and the code can't be copied and pasted. Instead, copy the code from your editor, [edit] your question and and paste it there. Thank you!

Comment: @EdgarC you're still not checking what's the value of getenv("QUERY_STRING").

Comment: @CormacO'Brien how would one go by doing that? Apologies, I'm still quite fresh in this topic

Comment: @EdgarC You would assign it to a variable and then test the value for NULL. `char *env_var = getenv("QUERY_STRING")`, and then `if (env_var == NULL) { /* handle error */ }`

Comment: "When I simply comment out that specific line, the code compiles and runes perfectly" - so comment it out, or better still, delete it. If the code compiles and runs perfectly without it, why are you trying to stick this extraneous stuff in there?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
parse(getenv("QUERY_STRING"));
```

by:

```
char *querystring = getenv("QUERY_STRING");

if (querystring == NULL)
{
  printf("Could not get querystring");
  exit(1);    
}

parse(querystring);
```

... and read the [documentation of `getenv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html).

Comment: That did indeed fix it, thank you. I'm sorry for being such a drag, I truly am blind regarding getenv for the time being. Have a nice day :)